# Python Selenium find_element_by_id with default if not found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to find an element on the page by id. The issue is that this element is only temporary and will not exist all of the time. Therefore I would like to set the default value so I can check for it in a conditional like so:

```
    covidPopUp = driver.find_element_by_id("sgpb-popup-dialog-main- 
    div").extract(default='not-found')

    if(covidPopUp == 'not-found'):
        load_more_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("load_more_button")
        load_more_btn.click()
    else:
        popUpClose = driver.find_element_by_id("sgpb-popup-close-button-6")
        popUpClose.click()
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options.

1. Use [`find_element_by_id`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_id) but catch the exception

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    covidPopUp = driver.find_element_by_id("sgpb-popup-dialog-main-div")
except NoSuchElementException:
    covidPopUp = "not-found"
```

2. Use [`find_elements_by_id`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_id) (note plural) and check if list is not empty.

```py
covidPopUp = driver.find_elements_by_id("sgpb-popup-dialog-main-div")
covidPopUp = covidPopUp[0] if covidPopUp else "not-found"
```